# Smart dimmer Wi-Fi (Globe or C-GE) to old wiring?

Tags: smart-switch

Wiring smart globe dimmer switch with white, black, green red but my box is old and I only have black white and cooper.  Sure no neutral.  Help please.

Comment: Can you post photos of insides of both the light and switch boxes please?

Answer (score 3):

So you have a white wire and black wire going to your existing switch and a bare copper ground in the box too. You have a hot, a switched hot and a ground wire. Your new switch has a hot (black), a red(load) and a white (neutral) oh wait!! you don't have a neutral in your box. You'll have to get a dimmer that doesn't require a neutral... they're out there, just have to look for one.